# FileNotFoundException while dockerized java spring boot application start

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-compose, dockerfile

## The json file I use in my project cannot be found, what could be the reason?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psoLi.png)

```
countriesspringbootproject-countries-springboot-1  | java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/countries.json (No such file or directory)
countriesspringbootproject-countries-springboot-1  |    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
countriesspringbootproject-countries-springboot-1  |    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216)
countriesspringbootproject-countries-springboot-1  |    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
countriesspringbootproject-countries-springboot-1  |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TokenStreamFactory._fileInputStream(TokenStreamFactory.java:262)
countriesspringbootproject-countries-springboot-1  |    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:1030)
```

## this is my dockerfile

```
FROM mysql

FROM openjdk:latest

WORKDIR /app

ADD src/main/resources/countries.json /app/countries.json

COPY target/*.jar app.jar

CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

## this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql_db:
    image: mysql
    environment: 
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'countries'
      MYSQL_USER: 'hum'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '414141'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    volumes:
        - ./mysql/db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
        - '5555:3306'
    networks:
      - country-mysql
  countries-springboot:
    image: countries-springboot
    build: .
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql_db:3306/countries
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - '4141:8080'
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
    networks:
      - country-mysql
networks:
  country-mysql:
```

My LoadJson.java class

```
    package com.hum.countriesrestapi.Utils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.hum.countriesrestapi.model.Country;

@Component
public class LoadJson {
    private final static String COUNTRY_JSON = "src/main/resources/countries.json";
    public Map<String, Country> countries;
    public List<Country> countriesList = new ArrayList<>();

    public  List<Country> loadJson() { // JSON dosyasını okur ve verileri nesnelere dönüştürür
        
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try{
            Map<String, Map<String, Object>> countryMaps = objectMapper.readValue(new File(COUNTRY_JSON), new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>() {});
            countries = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Object>> entry : countryMaps.entrySet()) {
            String countryCode = entry.getKey();// anahtar String kısmı countrycode'a atandı
            Map<String, Object> countryMap = entry.getValue(); // her bir ülke için bir Country nesnesi oluşturulur ve bu nesneler bir Map<String, Country> nesnesinde saklanır
            Country country = objectMapper.convertValue(countryMap, Country.class);//Map nesnesindeki özellikleri, Country sınıfındaki alanlarla eşleştirerek yeni bir Country nesnesi oluşturur
            country.setId(countryCode); //country nesnesinin id alanı countryCode'a ayarlanır
            country.setName((String) countryMap.get("name"));
            country.setNativeName((String) countryMap.get("native")); //country nesnesinin nativeName  alanı native'e ayarlanır
            String phoneStr = (String) countryMap.get("phone");
            int phone = Integer.parseInt(phoneStr);
            country.setPhone(phone);
            country.setContinent((String) countryMap.get("continent"));
            country.setCapital((String) countryMap.get("capital"));
            country.setCurrency((String) countryMap.get("currency"));
            //country.setLanguages(Arrays.asList(countryMap.get("languages")));
            List<Object> languages = objectMapper.convertValue(countryMap.get("languages"), new TypeReference<List<Object>>() {});
            country.setLanguages(languages);
            country.setFlag("http://aedemirsen.bilgimeclisi.com/country_flags/" + countryCode + ".svg"); // flag özelliğini ayarla
            //countries.put(countryCode, country);// her bir ülke için oluşturulan country nesnesini countries mapine countryCode key'i ile ekler
            countriesList.add(country);
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return countriesList;
    } 
}
```

I'm making a request. I want to load the data in json into my mysql database and use them in my spring boot project. It was working fine in local but after dockerizing my mysql and java spring boot project I started to have this problem. How can I fix?

Both Docker and my database work in my project, but my JSON format file cannot be found. How can I fix?